# How can I find and replace between ( ) characters using regex?

Tags: regex, sed, notepad++

I  want to change a string just like below. But I couldn't find out the exact regex pattern.

**Strings like:**

Stack Overflow (1234)

Stack exchange (12)

**That I want is to proceed like**

Stack Overflow

Stack Exchange

I'm using Notepad++, UltraEdit etc. Also It would be very useful to try sed command too .

Thanks everybody

Comment: I tried [(*)] pattern.  But it is only finding the ( or )  characters , not all characters between two characters"()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this find:

```
\s+\([^)]+\)
```

And replace by nothing.

`\s+` matches spaces.

`\(` matches an opening parenthesis.

`[^)]+` matches any character except a closing parenthesis.

`)` matches a closing parenthesis.

---

`[(*)]` will match any one of `(`, `*` or `)` because they are in a character class.

You can otherwise use `\s+\(.*?\)` as well, but it's not as safe as the regex above. In regex, the dot is the wildcard and brackets are used for capture; that's why I had to escape them with backslashes. You don't need to escape them in a character class, like for instance, you can use this: `\s+[(].*?[)]` though it's a bit longer!

Comment: This is so useful.. This is what I want. Thanks to you for knowledge sharing and fixing my problem

Comment: This will replace `Test (testje) more text (12345)` with `Test more text`. I don't know if this is wanted behavior.

Comment: @Broxzier I'm sure that if OP wanted to keep `(testje)` in your example, it would have been mentioned.

Comment: Pure explaining you guys are awesome. I admire enviously to all of you

Comment: @user2182319 As long as you have your attempt with your question, you're good to get answers back ;)

Comment: How can I find only numbers ? Should I  change string as \s+\([0-9]+\) just for numbers

Comment: [0-9]  is worked :) I really appreciate for all of yours efforts. You saved my hours

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Notepad++ but using sed it is a simple command:

```
 sed -i.bak 's/ *(.*$//' file
```

`-i` is for inline editing (it will save the converted file with original saved as `file.bak`)

Comment: Thank you so so much.  I will try in sed too. What a nice to know there is gurus on REGEX

Answer (score 0):

Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>):

```
^(.+?)\s*\(\d+\)$
```

By:

```
$1
```

This is how it works:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Everything in Group 1 is kept, the rest is dropped.

Comment: Thanks but this selected whole line,  and the replacing with $1 dşd not work

Comment: @user2182319 It selects the whole line, and replaces it by the part in Group 1. I tested it on Notepad++ myself.

Comment: Hmm,  while trying your code I had used only Programmer's Notepad not Notepad++.  Because the file is over 1 G.

Comment: But awesome explaining.  You know what, I started to interest in REGEX. You are explaining very simple and pure. Are you writing tutorials about regex ?

Comment: @user2182319, No I'm not, I just like playing around with it and learned bit by bit after time. Being interested helps a lot and there are many tutorials out there!

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
awk '{sub(/ \(.+\)/,x)}1' file
```